# Does masking with Snap.svg work in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, svg, mask, masking, snap.svg

I have tried the "Getting Started" tutorial on the Snap.svg website and also attempted duplicating the code found here http://codepen.io/rachsmith/pen/FzAGt

But I just can't seem to get the SVG masking to work.

Have other people had this issue?  As far as I can tell the only difference between the way I set it up and the tutorials online is my use of the AngularJS framework.

Comment: Could you post it up on a fiddle ?

Comment: unfortunately no, our environment is not open to the public =\

Comment: did u ever figure out what was wrong? I'm getting the exact same problem with masking, also using angular. Specifically, this setup: https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Answer (score 2):

At a basic level it seems to work.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('mySvg', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var s = Snap(120, 120);
            element.append(s.node);   
            var first = s.circle(40, 60, 40).attr({
                fill: "#888"
            });
            var second = s.circle(80, 60, 40).attr({
                fill: "#fff"
            });
            first.attr({
                mask: second
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See the code on fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/83Gd4/1/